# Does restarting Windows spin down your hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, reboot

When I restart, does my hard drive come to a stop or spin down? I ask because I know that this can be damaging to mechanical drives, so I'm trying to kind of optimize the health of my HDDs by not restarting so often if that's true.

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: It makes no difference: most modern HDD power-down after some time, even while the PC is in active use. This can be annoying with external HDD's which may run for only 15 seconds at a time. This feature saves power, and reduces heating of the drive, which is also damaging.

Comment: If you are restarting your PC the proper way (you actually click on the Restart button in the Start menu), then it shouldn't have any consequences for the HDD. However, a hard restart (using the power button) might actually damage the drive if it's still writing/reading data. The OS restarts/shuts down all the functions and hardware components 1 by 1 during the process. Whereas a hard reset might actually corrupt the hardware. The surest way to avoid such failures is to always keep backups somewhere else off-site. Components can be swapped/changed, but data cannot be replaced! Good luck!